# "Super +D" hides copy dialog forever

Tags: unity, nautilus, 15.04, dialog

How to show the 'copy progress window' after hiding it?.

<kbd>Super</kbd> +<kbd>D</kbd> hides copy dialog forever, selecting "show copy dialog" or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not have any effect.

The small progress bar is visible in the launcher icon of unity. How to show the 'copy progress window' after hiding it?.

Comment: The bug has appeared [earlier](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/887821).

Comment: This bug happened to me today on 16.04 when copying large files to a USB drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a bug. Do as follows:

1. Unlock Nautilus from the launcher.
2. Logout/login.
3. Run Bleachbit.
4. Lock the Nautilus back again.

Comment: This bug has been present for years. Why don't they fix it?  I'm in the middle of a 17 hour copy of 1TB of data to a backup drive (usb 2, portable drive).  It's not convenient to log out now.  How do I know when the copy has finished?

Comment: @DrEval Therefore, I use Grsync. It performs incremental copy, so very good for backup and uses checksum for reliability.  It has so many other options as well.